# react-native 0.59 on xcode 13 build error on ios

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode13

I have an existing project but I got a new macbook with m1.

When running ios I got an error.

```
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find instruments 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
error Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find instruments 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

I found that instrument was deprecated on xcode 13.

Is there any work around for this one?

Thank you